Terraform - Creating an AWS S3 Bucket Policy Error -MalformedPolicy: Unknown field version
I'm creating and working in a Terraform Project that creates an AWS S3 Bucket for use as a static website.
I have created a "Public Access Block" and added a further resource to create an "AWS S3 Bucket Policy" to Allow anyone public access to "GetObject" from the bucket/site.
Unfortunately when running a "terraform apply" command I receive an error:
Error: putting S3 Bucket (terraform-course-project-1-d4f420c9) Policy: operation error S3: PutBucketPolicy, https response error StatusCode: 400, RequestID: AN81J2DNCPWB9S2R, HostID: w93iACwvYDKdAv4a6ZyoYWf3u3TdFdQon+FrwvHb/qprNh27w7VMpSDS+Nry+Xa+XAttzJoQY4o237FHACL7Whd0qlhGNC16, api error MalformedPolicy: Unknown field version
│
│   with aws_s3_bucket_policy.static-website-public-read,
│   on s3.tf line 17, in resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "static-website-public-read":
│   17: resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "static-website-public-read" {

The code I'm using:
resource "random_id" "bucket_suffix" {
  byte_length = 4
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "static_website" {
  bucket = "terraform-project-s3-web-${random_id.bucket_suffix.hex}"
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_public_access_block" "static_website" {
  bucket                  = aws_s3_bucket.static_website.id
  block_public_acls       = false
  block_public_policy     = false
  ignore_public_acls      = false
  restrict_public_buckets = false
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "static-website-public-read" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.static_website.id

  policy = jsonencode({
    version = "2012-10-17"
    Statement = [
      {
        Sid       = "PublicReadGetObject"
        Effect    = "Allow"
        Principal = "*"
        Action    = "s3:GetObject"
        Resource  = "${aws_s3_bucket.static_website.arn}/*"
      }
    ]
  })
}

How to get this policy to apply? I cannot find any information on internet crawl to explain the error, especially: "api error MalformedPolicy: Unknown field version".
Have read similar posts regarding the issue but none found for the "Unknown Field" error.

It is specifically saying:

Unknown field version

It is telling you the version field is unknown. I believe it is because the policy is case sensitive, and it should be Version with an uppercase V.
Try comparing what you have to some examples in the official documentation.

Apply complete! Resources: 7 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.
Outputs:
static_website_endpoint = "terraform-project-s3-web-88ca5d68.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com"

Please accept the answer if it answered your question.

Thanks a million Mark B - A simple error with a lower case "v" in version as you stated, changed to upper case "Version" and it worked immediately! - Only wasted about 3 hours changing code to no avail :0(
